# Yii2 GridView speed uptimaization

Tags: gridview, yii2

I create grid view in yii2 and I have 2400 data which is not so much but the loading time of grid is so much. I populate data from mysql database view. Please can you explain me how to speed up the grid view?

Here is my code:

```
  public function search($params) {
        $this->load($params);

    $query = (new Query)
            ->select('*')
            ->from('view_quotation_grid')
            ->orderBy('referenceno DESC');

    if ($this->referenceno != "") {
        //$query->andFilterWhere(['like', '', $this->referenceno]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'referenceno', $this->referenceno]);
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'customer_name', $this->customer_name]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'product_model', $this->product_model]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'quotation_status', $this->quotation_status]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'is_confirm', $this->is_confirm]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'net_total', $this->net_total]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'doc_date', $this->doc_date]);

    $pages = clone $query;
    $pages->select('COUNT(*) count');
    $pages = $pages->createCommand()->queryAll();
    $pages = $pages[0];

    $command = $query->createCommand();
    $sql = $command->sql;
    $params = $command->params;

    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
        'sql' => "$sql",
        'params' => $params,
        'totalCount' => $pages['count'],
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => [
                'sr',
                'referenceno' => [
                    'asc' => ['referenceno' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['referenceno' => SORT_DESC],
                    'default' => SORT_DESC,
                    'label' => 'referenceno',
                ],
                'customer_name' => [
                    'asc' => ['customer_name' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['customer_name' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'customer_name',
                ],
                'quotation_status' => [
                    'asc' => ['quotation_status' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['quotation_status' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'quotation_status',
                ],
                'is_confirm' => [
                    'asc' => ['is_confirm' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['is_confirm' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'is_confirm',
                ],
                'net_total' => [
                    'asc' => ['net_total' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['net_total' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'net_total',
                ],
                'doc_date' => [
                    'asc' => ['doc_date' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['doc_date' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'doc_date',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 25,
        ],
    ]);

    $models = $dataProvider->getModels();

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: if some one know how to create gridview from sql procedure so plz mention thanks

Comment: Try to execute SQL queries separately (outside of GridView) for getting data (with applied filters) and for count and see execution time. You can use `EXPLAIN` for deeper investigation. Also you can use Yii debug panel and browser console, maybe this is not database issue, but assets loading issue for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove excess method call:

```
$models = $dataProvider->getModels();
```

Simplify evaluating total count (use only PK column instead `*`):

```
$pages = clone $query;
$pages->select('COUNT(*) count');
$pages = $pages->createCommand()->queryAll();
$pages = $pages[0];

// ...

'totalCount' => $pages['count'],
```

replace by:

```
$queryClone = clone $query;
$totalCount = $queryClone->count('[[id]]');     // where [[id]] is PrimaryKey
```

Try to add indexes for columns that used in where/order_by statement.

Also use [debug extensions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-debug-index.html) to profiling SQL queries. It show time that performed each SQL query, and allows to execute `EXPLAIN` command for each query.